# Markov chain and invariant measure

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Consider a recurrent irreducible Markov chain $X$ taking values in a countable set $E$ and $\mu$ an invariant measure. Let $F \subset E$ be finite and $T_F=\inf\{n \in \mathbb{N}^*,X_n \in F\}.$

Prove that $$\forall y \in F,\sum_{x \in F}\mu(x)P_x(X_T=y)=\mu(y).$$

We know that $T_F$ is finite a.s. I tried to write $\sum_{x \in F}\mu(x)P_x(X_T=y)=\sum_{x \in F}\mu(x)P_x(X_n=y,T=n)$ but this seems to complicate the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By irreducibility, $\mu(x)>0$ for all $x$. Consider the reversed chain $\{Y_n\}$ with transition matrix
$$Q(x,y):=\mu(y)P(y,x)/\mu(x) \,.$$
This chain is also recurrent (since $Q^n(z,z)=P^n(z,z)$ yields a divergent sum) and $\mu$ is stationary for $Q$ as well. Let $\tau=\inf\{n \in \mathbb{N}^*,Y_n \in F\},$  which is finite a.s. by recurrence. Then for any states  $z_0,z_1,\ldots,z_{k}$, we have  (by induction on $k$) that
$$\mu(z_0)P(z_0,,z_1)  \cdots  P(z_{k-1},z_k)  =\mu(z_k)Q(z_{k},z_{k-1}) \cdots Q(z_1,z_0) \,. \quad (*)$$
Take $z_0=x$ and $z_k=y$. By summing $(*)$ over all $z_1,\ldots,z_{k-1} \notin F$,  we obtain
$$ \mu(x)P_x(T=k, \, X_T=y)=\mu(y)Q_y(\tau=k, \, Y_\tau=x)\,.$$
Summing over $k$ gives
$$ \mu(x)P_x(X_T=y)=\mu(y)Q_y(Y_\tau=x)\,.$$
Therefore for $ y \in F$,
$$ \sum_{x \in F}\mu(x)P_x(X_T=y)=\sum_{x \in F}\mu(y)Q_y(Y_\tau=x)=\mu(y).$$

Comment: @mathex Regarding your first comment: This is not true. The identity in the third comment does hold. Do you know how to answer the original question via this identity? Did you follow the solution I posted, or is something unclear there?

Comment: If you understand my answer to your question, you can accept it, and then ask another question separately. Asking follow-up questions in comments is discouraged. Also, people might not answer your future questions if you ignore the answers provided to your previous questions.

Comment: Regarding the alternative calculation you proposed: When you sum over all $x \in E$, this sum is likely to be infinite, and $\infty=\infty$ is not that useful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135769/discussion-between-yuval-peres-and-mathex).

Comment: In your question you did not assume reversibility of the original chain. For reversible chains the argument is easier, you can just sum over paths as noted in Theorem 13.16 in https://pages.uoregon.edu/dlevin/MARKOV/mcmt2e.pdf

Comment: We can prove it if and only if the original chain is reversible.

Comment: Our discussion was moved to https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135769/discussion-between-yuval-peres-and-mathex

Comment: Mathex, please do not add comments here! Our discussion was moved to chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135769/…